# Reformatting date in google spreadsheet

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm setting up a spreadsheet for someone else with a form to enter data. 
One of the columns is supposed to hold a date. The input date format is like this example: "Jan 26, 2013" (there will be a lot of copy & paste involved to collect data, so changing the format at input step is not a real option).

I need this date column to be sortable, but the spreadsheet doesn't recognize this as a date but simply as a string. (It would recognize "Jan-26-2013", I've tried.)
So I need to reformat the input date.

My question is: how can I do this? I have looked around and google apps script looks like the way to go (though I haven't found a good example of reformatting yet). 
Unfortunately my only programming experience is in Python, and of intermediate level. I could do this in Python without a problem, but I don't know any JavaScript. 
(My Python approach would be:

```
splitted = date.split()
newdate = "-".join([splitted[0], splitted[1][:-1], splitted[2]])
return newdate
```

)

I also don't know how I'd go about linking the script to the spreadsheet - would I attach it to the cell, or the form, or where? And how? Any link to a helpful, understandable tutorial etc. on this point would help greatly.

Any help greatly appreciated!

**Edit: Here's the code I ended up with:**

```
//Function to filter unwanted " chars from date entries
function reformatDate() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startrow = 2;
  var firstcolumn = 6;
  var columnspan = 1;
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var dates = sheet.getRange(startrow, firstcolumn, lastrow, columnspan).getValues();
  newdates = []
  for(var i in dates){
    var mydate = dates[i][0];
    try
      {
      var newdate = mydate.replace(/"/g,'');
      }
    catch(err)
      {
      var newdate = mydate
      }
     newdates.push([newdate]);
  }
  sheet.getRange(startrow, firstcolumn, lastrow, columnspan).setValues(newdates)
}
```

For other confused google-script Newbies like me:

- attaching the script to the spreadsheet works by creating the script from within the spreadsheet (Tools => Script Editor). Just putting the function in there is enough, you don't seem to need a function call etc.
- you select the trigger of the script from the Script Editor (Resources => This Project's Triggers).

**Important:** the script will only work if there's an empty row at the bottom of the sheet in question!

Comment: Glad to hear my answer was helpful :-)

Comment: @Serge: yes, it was, thank you! I somehow couldn't comment or upvote/accept yesterday. Does the above code look sensible to you or is it needlessly complicated? (Since I don't know anything about JavaScript I'd appreciate feedback.)

Comment: I edited my answer, it's easier than in comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an idea :

If you double click on your date string in the spreadsheet you will see that its real value that makes it a string instead of a date object is this `'Jan 26, 2013`  with the `'` in front of the string that I didn't add here...(The form does that to allow you to type what you want in the text area, including +322475... for example if it is a phone number, that's a known trick in spreadsheets cells) You could simply make a script that runs [on form submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers?hl=en) and that removes the `'` in the cells, I guess the spreadsheet would do the rest... (I didn't test that so give it a try and consider this as a suggestion).

To remove the `'` you can simply use the `.replace()` [method **](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

```
var newValue = value.replace(/'/g,'');
```

here are some links to the relevant documentation : [link1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events)  [link2](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers#ActionTriggers)

---

**EDIT following your comment :**

It could be simpler since the `replace` doesn't generate an error if no match is found. So you could make it like this :

```
function reformatDate() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dates = sheet.getRange(2, 6, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  newdates = []
  for(var i in dates){
    var mydate = dates[i][0];
      var newdate = mydate.replace(/"/g,'');
     newdates.push([newdate]);
  }
  sheet.getRange(2, 6, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).setValues(newdates)
}
```

Also, you used the `"` in your code, presumably on purpose... my test showed `'` instead. What made you make this choice ?

Comment: I changed the quotation mark because I found that in the spreadsheet I'm working on, this is the quotation mark that is actually used. As for the try/catch: I tried it without, but then got an error whenever 'mydate' was already '"'-free, since then they are automatically converted to Date objects (which is what I intended) and Date objects don't seem to support the 'replace' function. So the rest of the function makes sense that way? That's a huge relief, thank you! :-)

Comment: thanks for the complementary infos ;-), you're right, I didn't think about the case of the cell being already a date...so, the try/catch is a way to go..., another possible way is to use typeOf() to see wether it's a string or not. About the quotation mark, I'm wondering why your spreadsheet is different ? I have no idea so far, if ever I find something I'll update here. Anyway, case closed for now ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, I just had to change the comma to dot and it worked